# Image height is not changing

Tags: image, flutter, listtile

I'm trying to change the image height but it's not changing.

here is my code

```
 ListTile(
     
          leading: ClipRRect(
            borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(10.0),
            child: Image.network(
              book.urlImage,
              fit: BoxFit.cover,
              width: 55,
              height: 90,
            ),
          ),
```

Comment: see https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/material/ListTile-class.html - they say: *"A single fixed-height row that typically contains some text as well as a leading or trailing icon."* - if you need more info read subsequent paragraphs

Answer (score 1):

By default the `ListTile's` maximum leading widget height would be 56px.

This is the source code of `ListTile`,

```dart
final Offset baseDensity = visualDensity.baseSizeAdjustment;
if (isOneLine)
  return (isDense ? 48.0 : 56.0) + baseDensity.dy;
if (isTwoLine)
  return (isDense ? 64.0 : 72.0) + baseDensity.dy;
return (isDense ? 76.0 : 88.0) + baseDensity.dy;
```

You can see the maximum height of leading widget for each condition. 90px wouldn't be possible. If 90px is what you want then consider making your own `ListTile` with `Row` and `Column`.

Comment: oh, i see! thanks for letting me know

Answer (score 0):

**Have you tried putting the Listtile in a container?**

**In this way -->**

```
Container(
        width: 100,
        height: 100,
        decoration: BoxDecoration(
          image: DecorationImage(
            image: AssetImage(
             'assets/horoscopes/${horoscope.toLowerCase()}.png'),
          ),
          borderRadius: const BorderRadius.all(
            Radius.circular(25.0),
          ),
        ),
      ),
```

Comment: yeah, but that's not working!

Answer (score 0):

Set your image in SizedBox child

```
SizedBox(
  width: 50,
  height: 90,
  child: Image.network( 
     book.urlImage, 
     fit: BoxFit.cover,
  ),
)
```

Comment: that's not working!

Answer (score 0):

Try below code hope its help to you.

```
 ListTile(
            leading: Container(
              width: 150.0,
              height: 100.0,
              decoration: BoxDecoration(
                border: Border.all(
                  color: Colors.grey.shade500,
                ),
                image: DecorationImage(
                  image: NetworkImage(
                    'https://tech.pelmorex.com/wp-content/uploads/2020/10/flutter.png',
                  ),
                ),
                //shape: BoxShape.circle,
              ),
            ),
          ),
```

Your Result Screen-> [image]